# Return random rows only once in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, random

I am trying to retrieve random rows from mysql using `RAND()` function. But in result rows are repeating more than once. Is there any way to return random rows in such a way that a row is returned only once?

My query is: `SELECT h.recid recid, h.name name, h.subtitle subtitle, h.pricingfrom pricingfrom FROM holydays h ORDER BY RAND()`

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773850/mysql-return-random-rows-with-possible-duplicates) solution but I didnt understand how it works as I don't have any limits...
Any answer will be appreciated.!

Answer (score 1):

The `ORDER BY` clause of a query has nothing to with the result set, except maybe if `LIMIT` is being used, which it is not here.  It sounds to me like your table has some duplicate records.  If you want a random ordering with no duplicates, then select with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    recid,
    name,
    subtitle,
    pricingfrom
FROM holydays
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Comment: my table doesn't contain any duplicate entries. I tried using  `DISTINCT` but still the same result

Comment: @Aishwaryas If you select distinct, then you _can't_ get duplicate records.  So now the issue is how are you defining "duplicate?"

Answer (score 0):

it's work by order by taking random columns
ex, there is id, name, emai then some time it order id,name,email or some time name,id,emai etc. etc. and it some time order in asc and some time in desc. That's logic.

Comment: so what should I do to achieve my task?